# Why custom 404 page not loading when using build project from Nextjs application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

I have a custom 404 page for my Nextjs app. I wanted to try the build project locally before deploying it to server. I used the "serve" package to host the project locally. The project loads fine but when I tried to navigate to a page that doesn't exist, the app uses the default 404 page and not the customized one. I just want to ask if there are needed steps to configure in order to run the custom 404 page from Next.js or if it is possible to load the custom 404 page locally.

##### In the browser:

[image: Browser]

##### 404.tsx file:

[image: 404.tsx file]

##### next.config file:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(html)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    })
    return config
  },
}
```

##### 404.tsx

```
export default function FourOhFour() {
  return <>
    <h1>404 - Page Not Found - Test 404 Page</h1>
  </>
}
```

Comment: This also can happen if you have set `fallback: true` in `getStaticPaths`, although the docs are a bit misleading here, IMO: [data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true).

Answer (score 3):

you create in `pages/404.js (or .tsx)`
You don't need to change `config`, the page will be rendered in case of 404.

Maybe you have `cache` problem (delete your `.next` folder and try to build again)

P.S. probably you will need to add your `"pages/404.js"` to `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Delete `.next` folder and build again works for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

The "serve" package does not allow you to customise the 404 page (from the doc). The page to serve in case of 404 is a server configuration, for instance, on nginx you can configure it with the directive `error_page 404 /404.html;`.

You need to look in the your web server doc how to configure 404 pages.